# Parent setState works yet setState inside child does not

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following code structure (simplified):

This is the parent:

```
 //code...

 const {handleClick} = useClick;

 <ul>
   {actions.map((action: string) => (
      <li onClick={() => handleClick()} key={uuidv4()}>
         {getAction(action, id)}
      </li>
   ))}
</ul>
```

`getAction` is the following:

```
export const getAction = (
  action: string,
  id: number | string
): JSX.Element | null => {

   switch (action) {
    case Actions.submit_recall: {
      return <Report {...{ id }} />;
    }

   //code...
};
```

`Report` is the following:

```
export const Report = ({ id }: ReportType): JSX.Element | null => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)}>Report a Recall</div>

      <Modal
        open={isModalOpen}
      >

     //code...

)};
```

Some context:
When you click on the li element, is supposed to both hide the `ul` on the parent and open the `modal` inside the `Report` component. Yet currently it only hides the `ul` element.

When I click on the `li` element inside the parent, the function `handleClick` does get called, yet clicking on the `div` inside the `Report` component does not trigger `setIsModalOpen()`. I tried console.log a value when clicking on the `div`, and it does work...

The `handleClick` is nothing more than:

```
const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
```

```
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("hi");
          return setIsModalOpen(true);
        }}
```

[image]

What I don't follow is that, if I eliminate or comment the `handleClick` inside the parent, the function `setIsModalOpen` inside `Report` works as intended.

I had suspected that when I successfully hid the 'ul' element, I was also hiding the `modal` since is inside the parent yet I confirmed that is not the case since I manually hide the `ul` (with CSS, no react logic), manually open the modal. Also, was checking the react profiler extension.

Bottom line, when the `handleClick` function runs, `setIsModalOpen` function does not. Why? ...the desired behavior is when clicking on the `li` element inside the parent, the `ul` should hide (alongside the `li`), and the modal should stay open.

Sorry if I wasn't specific enough, thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm guessing `key={uuidv4()}` causes a new UUID to be generated every render which means your components are always mounted anew. Local state would be wiped out because you have a new key/new component instance. Remove the key for a moment and see what happens (default is index). It should be a persisted key like an ID, or React 18 useId() or index if you understand what it means to have an index key (makes sense if elements in your map never change order)

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. 

Thanks for the help, and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since this comment ended up as the answer:

I'm guessing `key={uuidv4()}` causes a new UUID to be generated every render which means your components are always mounted anew.

Local state would be wiped out because you have a new key/new component instance.

Remove the key for a moment and see what happens (default is index).

It should be a persisted key like an ID, or React 18 useId() or index if you understand what it means to have an index key (makes sense if elements in your map never change order)